# How to parse the response in JSON file from SOAP request in Android application

Tags: android, soap

My SOAP request and SOAP response is as follows:

```
Test
To test the operation using the HTTP POST protocol, click the 'Invoke' button.
Parameter   Value
accessCode: xxxxxx
            Invoke     


SOAP 1.1
```

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /UI/WebServices/CalManager.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: login.nediso.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://nediso.com/add/login"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <add_x002F_login xmlns="http://nediso.com/">
      <accessCode>string</accessCode>
    </add_x002F_login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <add_x002F_loginResponse xmlns="http://nediso.com/">
      <add_x002F_loginResult>string</add_x002F_loginResult>
    </add_x002F_loginResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here I am sending the SOAP request as specified in the above SOAP request format with accesscode, let it be, for example, `xxxxx`. In the below I am getting the Response as string. whenever I am entering the access code and click on the Invoke button just above the SOAP request I am getting `.Json` file as response. Here the issue is whether I am getting String as a response or `.Json` file as response. If it is `.Json` file how to handle and parse it?

Comment: You should include some code so its easier to tell what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure what you mean exactly but it's easy to parse a json response from your request. You can use the google-gson library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Once you've added the library to your project, you can do something like:

```
public static String ParseJSON(String theResponse, String tag){
    try{
          String tempResp = theResponse.toUpperCase();
          String tempTag = tag.toUpperCase();
          JSONObject outer = new JSONObject(tempResp);
          String data = (String)outer.get(tempTag);
          return data;
        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
}
```

This function will return the `data` of the `tag` passed as a parameter. So for example:

```
String response = "Result:OK, Message:HI"; 
String msgData = ParseJSON(response, "Message");
System.out.println(msgData); //this will print "HI"
```

Ryan